# scala jar file executed by java - cp vs. jar

Tags: java, scala, jar

if I run:

```
java -jar corpus-tools-0.0.2.jar removeTSfromCorpus
```

it gives me error:

```
Failed to parse the trailing argument list: 'removeTSfromCorpus'
```

However, if I run:

```
java -cp corpus-tools-0.0.2.jar removeTSfromCorpus
```

It works seamlessly. scala-library is inlcuded in dependencies(MANIFEST).
What is difference in -cp and -jar? I think there should be equal in this case

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
java -cp jarfile classname
```

executes classname using the specified classpath (`-cp`). Instead of using the `-cp` option you could simply rely on the `CLASSPATH` variable to determine where `java` finds the classes.

```
java -jar jarfile
```

will use the specified `.jar` file and execute the `Main-Class` defined in the `.jar` file MANIFEST. This is java's close approximation to a standalone app. The app is packaged in the `.jar` file and the MANIFEST specifies the entry point within that `.jar` file. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for more details.

So (to answer your original question!) your first example will run a class specified in the MANIFEST, and that's trying to interpret `removeTSFromCorpus` as a command line argument in some fashion. Your second example sets the CLASSPATH to your .jar file and then runs `removeTSFromCorpus` as a class.

Answer (score 2):

When running a JAR the main class and classpath should be specified in the MANIFEST.MF file.

You then just run it like:

```
java -jar corpus-tools-0.0.2.jar
```

See:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Extract

> If you have an application bundled in a JAR file, you need some way to
>   indicate which class within the JAR file is your application's entry
>   point. You provide this information with the Main-Class header in the
>   manifest, which has the general form:
>
> Main-Class: classname

And

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Extract:

> You specify classes to include in the Class-Path header field in the
>   manifest file of an applet or application. The Class-Path header takes
>   the following form:
>
> Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name

Answer (score 1):

The `-jar` option is trying to execute the `static main` method from the main class defined in your jar file, then provides it with the argument `removeTSfromCorpus`.

The `-cp` option considers you are providing a classpath then trying to run the `main` method from the `removeTSFromCorpus` class.